# How to POST to node.js from applet?

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, applet, express

I have an applet (not our choice, it's the MarioAI engine) that I'd like to connect to a node.js app that uses express...but I can't seem to get mongodb to accept the values I'm sending in my POST request through localhost. I keep getting 200 response from node, but 'undefined' from mongooose, which I suspect means the URLEncoder I'm using in Java is mangling the String I'm sending through somehow.

I read this:

[Problem with Java Applet to connect our server to call a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989120/problem-with-java-applet-to-connect-our-server-to-call-a-php-file)

and tried the following OutputStreamWriter call in Java:

```java
//EvaluateFrustration() takes an int but should come back with a float value
String frustrationString = Double.toString(EvaluateFrustration(this.periods));
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8888/mario");               
    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
    conn.setUseCaches (false);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    OutputStreamWriter writer;


    writer = AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<OutputStreamWriter>() {
                    public OutputStreamWriter run() throws IOException {
                        return new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    }
                });
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("frustrationValueFirstRound=" 
                + frustrationString,"UTF-8");
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

In the node app (using express and mongoose/mongodb), I wrote:

```js
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var ExperimentSchema = new Schema({
    experiment    : ObjectId
    , frustrationValueFirstRound : Number
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mariopaper');
mongoose.model('Experiment', ExperimentSchema);
var Experiment = mongoose.model('Experiment');

app.post('/mario', function(req, res){
  var exp = new Experiment();
  exp.frustrationValueFirstRound = req.body.frustrationValueFirstRound;
  exp.save(function(err){   if (err) { throw err; }
  res.send('ok');
});
```

For reference, I'd like to point out that this curl call works just fine:

```
curl -d "frustrationValueFirstRound=99" http://localhost:8888/mario
```

Anyone have any ideas whether I've simply written the POST wrong in Java, or perhaps I'm missing something in how URLEncoder.encode() works?

Comment: also just to note, I tried this without the call through AccessController.doPrivileged but I saw on several posts that talking from applets to javascript needed permissions handling. I -have- tried without all that, still getting 'undefined'.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {
}`  Don't do that.  At least call `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java API for HTTP connections, but if I were you, I'd put Fiddler between the curl call and the Java call and compare the two posts.

Comment: dtryon: Fiddler seems to be windows only...

Comment: I added some catches to my try statement (MalformedURLException, IOException, and PrivilegedActionException), and I'm getting: Exception in thread "Game Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
 at java.net.URLConnection.setUseCaches(URLConnection.java:938)

Comment: Weird...-how- is it 'already' connected? I mean sure I set caching to false after url.openConnection() and I gave it a request type, but surely that's normal to do -after- connecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you don't have the body-parser node module, that "Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property."

Try this (after installing body-parser module):

```
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var ExperimentSchema = new Schema({
    experiment    : ObjectId
    , frustrationValueFirstRound : Number
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mariopaper');
mongoose.model('Experiment', ExperimentSchema);
var Experiment = mongoose.model('Experiment');

app.post('/mario', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body); // Is there something here ?
  var exp = new Experiment();
  exp.frustrationValueFirstRound = req.body.frustrationValueFirstRound;
  exp.save(function(err){   if (err) { throw err; }
  res.send('ok');
});
```

source : https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser